# C# add filter parameters and expression to listview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, filtering

I would like to dynamically set filtering of listview based on textboxes since I implicitly don't know the number and names of collumns. I've made it by creating Texboxes, setting filterparams and filterexpression in code behind - page is loading and working without any error but after changing text in any of textboxes listview is not filtering. When debuging I see that all filterexpression and filtercontrols exist with attributes I would expect. I really can't see any error and would appriciate any help. Thanks!

On Page_Load I have following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    // some code where I get datatable for my listview 
    // and put columns to tablecols

        tablecols = dtable.Columns;



    // creating of htmltablerow with textboxes for filtering

        HtmlTableRow htr_filterrow = new HtmlTableRow();
        htr_filterrow.ID = "filterrow"; 

        foreach (DataColumn col in tablecols)
        {
            HtmlTableCell htc = new HtmlTableCell();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "tb_" + col.ColumnName;

            htc.Controls.Add(tb);
            htr_filterrow.Controls.Add(htc);
        }

        placeholder_filterrow.Controls.Add(htr_filterrow);



    // setting filterparameters of my listview

        if (SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in tablecols)
            {
                ControlParameter filter_par = new ControlParameter();
                filter_par.Name = col.ColumnName;
                filter_par.ControlID = "ListView1$tb_" + col.ColumnName + "";
                filter_par.PropertyName = "Text";
                SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(filter_par);
            }
        }



   // setting filterexpression for my listview

        string filter_express = "";
        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataColumn col in tablecols)
        {
            if (filter_express.Length == 0)
            {
                filter_express = filter_express + " ([" + col.ColumnName + "] like '*{" + i + "}*' or [" + col.ColumnName + "] is null)";
            }
            else
                filter_express = filter_express + " and ([" + col.ColumnName + "] like '*{" + i + "}*' or [" + col.ColumnName + "] is null)";
            i = ++i;
        }   

            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = filter_express;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found my solution. It was DefaultValue set to filterparameters I have missed. Without DefaultValue this approach works fine for only one filterparameter but not for many.

After this change in my code it started to work.

```
ControlParameter search_par = new ControlParameter();
search_par.Name = "tb_search";
search_par.ControlID = "tb_search";
search_par.PropertyName = "Text";
search_par.DefaultValue = "*";
SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(search_par);
```